# android onCreate FragmentManager.getFragment null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewPager with 3 fragments inside another fragment.

Currently, i want to get a reference of the 3 fragments on the hosting fragment because i need to occasionally invoke some methods on them.

So i used putFragment and getFragment to save/restore these fragments.

Now, for some reason, i get a null pointer exception 
when I invoke             `f1 = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_1);`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:667)
at com.demo.android.view.MainFragment.onCreate(MainFragment.java:137)

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = this.getChildFragmentManager();
        f1 = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_1);
        f2 = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_2);
        f3 = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_3);
    }
    if (f1 == null)
        f1 = FragmentBuilder.builder().build();
    if (f2 == null)
        f2 = FragmentBuilder.builder().build();
    if (f3 == null)
        f3 = FragmentBuilder.builder().build();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    FragmentManager fm = this.getChildFragmentManager();
    fm.putFragment(outState, KEY_1, f1);
    fm.putFragment(outState, KEY_2, f2);
    fm.putFragment(outState, KEY_3, f3);
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find a solution? i'm into this and i cannot find a way to solve.

Comment: @MarcoCapoferri I didn't exactly find a solution to the null pointer exception. What I did instead is to loop through all the fragments in getChildFragmentManager().getFragments(); I got lucky in that my child fragments are all different types, so I can do a instanceof check to see which fragment is which. And get the reference that way.